# Cannot disable open documents in browser behavior in Chrome browser

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

In IE documents start downloading on click, but in Chrome Sharepoint trying to open them in Web App.
How can I make Chrome to download files like IE do?

**P.S.** OpenInClient feature is on